# Генерики - шаблонная лямбда

Tags: java, шаблоны, lambda, java-8

Собственно есть интерфейс

```
public interface Cmd<T extends A> {
    void exec(T a);
}
```

Как по нему записать лямбду так, чтобы определить тип `T` как `Ab` (`Ab implements A`)?

Вызывать я ее собираюсь примерно так:

```
if (a instanceof Ab){
    cmd.exec((Ab)a);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Честно говоря, из вопроса не очень понятно, что хочется увидеть в итоге, надеюсь, что попаду в цель

```
interface ListConsumer<T extends List> {
    void consume(T list);
}

ListConsumer<ArrayList<Integer>> consumer = list -> System.out.println(
        "List size: " + list.size())

...

applyConsumer((ListConsumer<ArrayList<Integer>>) list -> System.out.println(
        "List size: " + list.size()));
```